# How to assign data to ratingbar using databinding?

Tags: android, data-binding, ratingbar

I'm developing an app using databinding. I'm my app I have a ratingbar, now I need to assign rating to it using databinding.

Here is who i'm assign data to adapter xml and adapter class file

The xml look like:

```
 <RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/course_rating"
                style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/course_price_tv"
                android:layout_below="@+id/course_price"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_5"
                android:rating="@{course.courseRating}" />
```

The adapter class look like:

```
@BindingAdapter("android:rating")
    public void setRating(RatingBar view, float rating) {
        if (view.getRating() != rating) {
            view.setRating(rating);
        }
    }
```

I have gone through this [link](https://medium.com/@diegoy_kuri/fixing-nullpointerexception-when-trying-to-bind-ratingbar-rating-value-2e98034ad7dd), but I didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

method should be "static"

```
@BindingAdapter("android:rating")
    public static void setRating(RatingBar view, String rating) {

        if (view!=null)
        {

            float rate= Float.parseFloat(rating);

            view.setRating(rate);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I test this code just now, in my `item_main_tab.xml`:

```
<RatingBar
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:rating="@{4}" />
```

And then I check the generated code in `ItemMainTabBinding.java`:

```
public class ItemMainTabBinding extends android.databinding.ViewDataBinding  {
    @Override
    protected void executeBindings() {
        ...
        if ((dirtyFlags & 0x4L) != 0) {
            // api target 1

            this.mboundView2.setRating(4);  // see here
        }
    }
}
```

And everything is going well.

> So, you can check your generated code in `build/generated/source/kapt/debug/...`, and make sure the method `setRating()` has been invoked correctly.